# What type of application that allowed to auto-start in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, autostart

i wonder what type of application that are allowed to be started in the background/foreground when the iPhone boot , and are they limited to iOS 4 ?

Comment: If this allowed at all, expect extensive review of your app after you submit it. Autostart apps are a huge security risk. Apple will not allow minor problems that they might ignore in other apps.

Comment: Thats true, i'll keep that on mind if used it in my app. thanks for pointing out to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: None are allowed to.

Comment: I saw some article that says that Voip and GPS application are allowed to be running on the background but i didnt see an official link to Apple documentation .

Comment: That wasn't the question you asked.

Comment: what i meant is that i thought that there's one or two type of application that allowed. so i thought if you could provide a link to backup ur answer that would be good. Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to voip and navigation based apps, you're confusing automatic starting when the device boots with background tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Only Apple apps are allowed at startup, all others must be manually started.

Answer (score 1):

I think voip applications. That's what Apple documentation states anyway and yes, they are limited to iOS 4.0. You should declare your application as voip and make according changes in the code. See the link:
[Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: is apps that use background location cant use this feature ?

Comment: "Because VoIP applications need to stay running in order to receive incoming calls, the system automatically relaunches the application if it exits with a nonzero exit code. (This could happen in cases where there is memory pressure and your application is terminated as a result.)" It says nothing about GPS regarding reboot

Answer (score -1):

Background execution isn't supported by the iOS.  Apple takes many steps like this one to prevent the intrusion of their customers rights to privacy. If an app would be able to start on startup, then it would have no problem recording all activity such as GPS, saved files, and keystrokes. Apple doesnt feature, and probably will not feature multiple process handling (more then one third-party process running at once).

Comment: That can't be right about multi-third party apps. Have you tried Spotify (or most Radio apps) on an iPhone recently while you're doing other things? Didn't this come out in IOS 4?

Comment: Answer is pretty much totally made up. Even running apps can't do most of those things.