# task with action in background service

Tags: objective-c, ios, scheduled-tasks, nsnotifications, objective-c-runtime

I've been searching an googleing over one hour now and I'm not really sure of it's legal and possible to add some tasks in an background service that triggers an action ( and bring the app to the foreground ).

With tasks i mean that the background service is doing something on an indicated time. I know its possible to bring up the IOS alert with the notifications ect... But an simple notifiction is not good enough.

Actually I wanna play an video, and if this is not possible maybe the audio ? Since bringing the app to the foreground is not possible, or is it?

What are the options?

Comment: This has been asked several times on SO. See here for some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318019/what-type-of-application-that-allowed-to-auto-start-in-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not acceptable to take away the user from what they are doing, this applies to iOS since it's a one-thing at a time OS. How would you feel if an application switched to itself while you're playing, chatting or half-way reading an article?

Apple doesn't allow it, you should stick to the [Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html), and if the user truly wants to see/hear the video/audio, then he will go to your app.